# barebones c char pointer

Tags: c, assembly, operating-system

So I have been trying to dive a bit into os development, and got to the point where I can execute c (with gcc).

```
char* parameter = "test"
videoMemory[1] = *parameter;
videoMemory[2] = 0xcf;
```

When I execute the code I get nothing printed out except the red background (0xcf refers to foreground and background colors). I have also tried

```
videoMemory[1] = parameter[0];
```

and got nothing.
When executing

```
videoMemory[1] = 'X';
```

or

```
videoMemory[1] = "test"[0];
```

I get the X character printed out.
What do I have to do to get the string stored in the variable 'parameter' printed to the screen

*edit: link to project [[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D1xgfbL1uY7zY48Nm-x6QNvZOhh713n1/view?usp=sharing]](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D1xgfbL1uY7zY48Nm-x6QNvZOhh713n1/view?usp=sharing)

**SOLVED**
I have solved the issue. I used `char stringarray[] = ""`, and it works just as expected

Comment: There's not enough info here for help to be provided. Especially considering there is a whole custom OS behind this code not to mention that this is an out of context incomplete code snippet.

Comment: I have followed this tutorial [https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~exr/lectures/opsys/10_11/lectures/os-dev.pdf], but other than that my code is basically that snippet inside a main function, nothing more.

Comment: It's not reasonable to expect people to read a 77 page document to understand what you have done. You'll need to attempt to provide a [mre] in the question itself.

Comment: `videoMemory[1] = "test"[0];` prints an `X`?  What type does `videoMemory` have?  Is it `uint16_t` so it includes an ASCII char *and* an attribute byte?  If it's `uint8_t` then `videoMemory[1]` is the 2nd byte, holding the attributes for the first byte.  (Assuming you're in VGA text mode.)

Comment: If a (local?) `char stringarray[] = ""` was different from reading a pointer to a string literal, probably your kernel's `.rodata` section isn't where it's supposed to be.  A local array will get constructed on the stack, often with a few `mov`-immediate if it's smaller than a compiler's decision heuristic.  In that case it doesn't reference any static data, just code and the stack.

Answer (score 1):

You want to assign an individual character to the address in memory, like you did with `X` but you need to do it at the correct location.

`videoMemory[0] = 'X';` and at `videoMemory[1]` is where you would put color data about the character (if any)
If you want to add a second character, you would do so at index 2 like `videoMemory[2] = 'Y';`

To print out whole strings to the video memory, you will need to write a function, or set of functions, which keeps track of the position of the cursor on the screen, goes through each character in the string printing to the position of the cursor while advancing it each time.